# C++ put data from stack to file

Tags: c++

I still do not have much knowledge in C ++, I would like to ask for help for a task. I must create a stack, which is filled with data entered by the keyboard and the entire stack to write in external stack. I have made functions push, pop and simple program that displays the stack but before that data must be written in an external file. Can anybody help me with the external file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct elem
{ int key; elem *next;} *start=NULL, *p;


void push(int n)
{
    p=start;
    start=new elem;
    start->key=n;
    start->next=p;}

    int pop(int &n){
    if (start)
    {
        n=start->key;
        p=start;
        start=start->next;
        delete p;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;

}

int main(){
    int num;
    cout<<"Input integers:"<<setw(10);
    while (cin>>num)
    {
        push(num);
    }
    cout<<endl<<"Stack:"<<endl;
    while(pop(num))
    {
         cout<<num<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want a function in the stack (e.g. export() ) that will print it's data to a file, is that correct.

Comment: Your stack is a *single-linked list*, and if you can iterate over such a list then you know how to iterate over your stack. Then, you know how to write to `std::cout`, writing to other output streams is done just the same. Now combine these two concepts and you have your solution.

Comment: If you already know iostream, fstream is handled similarly, but works with files. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/fstream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//you can use this pseudocode

```
ofstream outFile;

while(start!=-1){
    outFile << pop() << endl;
```